# Comparing eigenvalues of A+B and A where both A and B are positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices

Suppose we have two positive definite matrices A and B. Is it correct to claim that all the eigenvalues of A+B are greater or equal to those of A?
Please note that:
1- I need to compare all the eigenvalues and not only the largest ones.
2- A and B are not necessarily diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  [Weyl's inequality for matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) shows that what you say is true.

Comment: The Courant minimax principle will work also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant_minimax_principle

Comment: Oh, Terry! You are so kind to answer this one, after your work on A. Horn's conjecture, now Tao-Knutson's theorem.